# How to make sense of the continuous state vector?

Tags: drake

## Background

I am trying to balance a mobile inverted pendulum (i.e. segway).

For the simulation, I created a simple robot that involves a pole attached to a cylinder (wheel) through a revolute joint.

### Question

After constructing my MIP plant, `plant.num_positions()` returns `8` and `plant.num_velocities()` returns `7`, i.e. the total `continuous_state` size is `15`

1. How do I make sense of this large number of states?
2. I suppose one of these represents the angle that the pole makes with the vertical.  How do I find that?
3. Also, why is `num_positions()` not equal to `num_velocities()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the urdf/sdf parser adds the system with a quaternion-based floating base.  This floating base joint has 7 position variables (x,y,z + quaternion) and 6 velocities (xdot, ydot, zdot, + spatial velocity).  You should use the multibody API to get the variable in the right order.

You can add a joint between the world link and your base (either in the urdf/sdf or in your code) to replace that implied floating joint with e.g. a prismatic joint at the base.

There are lots of examples of how to simulate it, in drake, but also at http://underactuated.mit.edu

Comment: I suppose by spatial velocity, you meant angular velocities (rolldot, pitchdot, yawdot)?

Comment: Side question, are there plans to make use of the `<sensor type="imu">` tag from `.sdf`  to allow drake to simulate the actual sensor values that gets fed to the controller?

Comment: Supporting IMU parsing isn't on the main developers short list.  We have some gyro + accelerometer classes that just need to be updated e.g. https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1sensors_1_1_gyroscope.html , and external code contributions.

Comment: Is it possible to specify to what link this quaternion-based floating base gets attached to?

Comment: After a bit of trial and error, I managed to figure out that from the vector output of `get_state_output_port`, index 6 is the z position.  I couldn't seem to find any documentation regarding this index mapping / order of the generalized positions.  Is it documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

From [Spatial Velocity](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_spatial_velocity.html)

> Spatial velocities are 6-element quantities that are pairs of ordinary 3-vectors. Elements 0-2 are the angular velocity component while elements 3-5 are the translational velocity.

From [QuaternionFloatingMobilizer](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/tree/quaternion_floating_mobilizer.cc#L34)

```
  // Note: In the context we store the quaternion's components first (q₀ to q₃),
  // followed by the position vector components (q₄ to q₆).
```