# No entry for variable u0_0 when converting from state_output to RollPitchYaw

Tags: drake

### Background

In order to control my `MultibodyPlant`, I need to know the current roll, pitch, yaw and x, y, z of a particular link.  I believe I obtain this information from my `MultibodyPlant`'s `get_state_output_port()`.  The plant is floating, i.e. it uses the [default quaternion-based floating base](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55713199/3177701).

### Problem

After decoding the meaning of the floating base state vector ([not sure if I did it right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55711025/how-to-make-sense-of-the-continuous-state-vector#comment99172140_55713199)) , I connect `get_state_output_port()` to the input port of my custom `LeafSystem` and try to convert the quaternion matrix to roll pitch yaw with the following line

```
Eigen::Quaternion<T> q(state[0], state[1], state[2], state[3]);
drake::math::RollPitchYaw<T> rpy(q);
```

This gives me the following `std::runtime_error`

```
what():  The following environment does not have an entry for the variable u0_0
```

How do I properly convert the current state into roll pitch yaw?

Comment: The error message indicates that you were running with T=symbolic::Expression. Was that your intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Sherm's comment, I need to [disable symbolic scalar conversion](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/structdrake_1_1systems_1_1scalar__conversion_1_1_non_symbolic_traits.html#details) for my custom LeafSystem since converting from quaternions to roll pitch yaw is not supported by `symbolic::Expression`

I had to add the following lines to the definition of my LeafSystem

```
namespace drake {
namespace systems {
namespace scalar_conversion {
template <> struct Traits<MyLeafSystem> : public NonSymbolicTraits {};
}  // namespace scalar_conversion
}  // namespace systems
}  // namespace drake
```